# solve for $x$ : $4^x = x^4$

Tags: exponential-function, index-notation

how to solve $x$ in $4^x = x^4$

My try:
$$ 4^x = x^4$$
$$ x \ln4 = 4 \ln x $$
$$ 2x\ln2 = 4 \ln x $$
$$ \frac{1}{2} x \ln2 = \ln x $$
$$ e^{\frac{1}{2} x \ln2} = x ....(1)$$
$$$$
$$\text{Let} : u = \frac{1}{2} x \ln 2 ....(2)$$
$$\text{then},  x = \frac{2u}{\ln 2} ....(3)$$

sub (2) and (3)into (1):
$$e^{u} = \frac{2u}{\ln 2}$$

And I have no idea of how to go on
...

Comment: you can immediately get $x=2$ as a solution just by inspection. Though, the question of whether this is the only solution is more involved (I think it is unique but I'm not too sure at the moment)

Comment: Google "lambert w-function"

Comment: $ x = 4 $ is also the answer

Comment: Why is this tagged natural transformations?

Comment: I think the linked question is a good place to look - if you want to quickly connect it to your work, note that your equation rewrites as $$\frac{\ln(2)}2 = ue^{-u}$$ or, if $v=-u$, as $$\frac{-\ln(2)}2 = ve^v$$ which is the step at which you need the product log - but look at the linked question, it's more detailed about this.

Comment: @UtkarshJha ah yes, of course I missed the even more obvious solution $x=4$.

Comment: it helps, thx @Milo Brandt